# How to turn items in a <datalist> into a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm trying to accomplish is give the user a text box where they can type a city name.  Based on what they type, US cities matching the text will be populated into a datalist.  Once the city they like is showing in the datalist, I want them to be able to click the city and be forwarded to a URL based on the city they've chosen.

I've worked out the first portion, I have the following html:

```js
function locationInputChange() {
  var val = $('#locationLookup').val();
  if (val === "") return;
  if (val.length < 3) return;
  console.log(val);
  $.post("/ContentService/HomeSearch", {
    q: val
  }, function(res) {
    var dataList = $("#locationlist");
    dataList.empty();
    if (res.length) {
      for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
        var opt = $("<option>" + res[i].Text + " </option>").attr("value", res[i].Value);
        dataList.append(opt);
      }
    }
  }, "json");
}
```

```html
<input list="locationlist" id="locationLookup" style="width:80%;" oninput="locationInputChange()" />
<datalist id="locationlist">
    </datalist>
```

and here is the js to get the matching results.  /ContentService/HomeSearch will return a json list of matching cities.

I have it working to get the matching results and return and populate the datalist with the relevant options, but I'm stuck as to how to create links out of the datalist.  I'm not married to the datalist avenue and I'm open to other methods to create the same effect.

Comment: A better design strategy is to include your data list in a form and then generate and redirect to links on submit